# How can I retrieve all the columns on a timerange aggregation?

Tags: mysql, impala

I am currently struggling on how to aggregate my daily data in other time aggregations (weeks, months, quarters etc).

Here is how my raw data type looks like:

```
| date     | traffic_type | visits  |
|----------|--------------|---------|
| 20180101 | 1            | 1221650 |
| 20180101 | 2            | 411424  |
| 20180101 | 4            | 108407  |
| 20180101 | 5            | 298117  |
| 20180101 | 6            | 26806   |
| 20180101 | 7            | 12033   |
| 20180101 | 8            | 80368   |
| 20180101 | 9            | 69544   |
| 20180101 | 10           | 39919   |
| 20180101 | 11           | 26291   |
| 20180102 | 1            | 1218490 |
| 20180102 | 2            | 410965  |
| 20180102 | 4            | 108037  |
| 20180102 | 5            | 297727  |
| 20180102 | 6            | 26719   |
| 20180102 | 7            | 12019   |
| 20180102 | 8            | 80074   |
```

First, I would like to check the **sum of visits** regardless of traffic_type:

```
SELECT date, SUM(visits) as visits_per_day
FROM visits_tbl
GROUP BY date
```

Here is the outcome:

```
|    ymd   | visits_per_day |
|:--------:|:--------------:|
| 20180101 |     2294563    |
| 20180102 |     2289145    |
| 20180103 |     2300367    |
| 20180104 |     2310256    |
| 20180105 |     2368098    |
| 20180106 |     2372257    |
| 20180107 |     2373863    |
| 20180108 |     2364236    |
```

However, if I want to check the specific day which the *visits_per_day* was the highest for each time aggregation (eg.: Month), I am struggling to retrieve the right output.

**Here is what I did:**

```
SELECT 
   (date div 100) as y_month, MAX(visits_per_day) as max_visit_per_day
FROM
    (SELECT date, SUM(visits) as visits_per_day
    FROM visits_tbl
    GROUP BY date) as t1
GROUP BY
   y_month
```

And here is the output of my query:

```
| y_month | max_visit_per_day |
|:-------:|:-----------------:|
|  201801 |      2435845      |
|  201802 |      2519000      |
|  201803 |      2528097      |
|  201804 |      2550645      |
```

However, I cannot know what was the exact day where the visits_per_day was the highest.

**Desired output:**

```
| y_month | max_visit_per_day |    ymd   |
|:-------:|:-----------------:|:--------:|
|  201801 |      2435845      | 20180130 |
|  201802 |      2519000      | 20180220 |
|  201803 |      2528097      | 20180325 |
|  201804 |      2550645      | 20180406 |
```

**ymd** would represent the day in which the visits_per_day was the highest.
This logic would be used in a dashboard with the help of programming in order to automatically select the time aggregation.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Any reason for inventing your own `DATE` representation rather than using the MySQL `DATE` datatype? Date logic is such a pain in the neck to get right that most people use the inbuilt data types.

Comment: Using the MySQL date type would make this possible. Then you could use the built-in functions.

Comment: @O.Jones I believe I can use the date function. It's no problem. I just represented the way it is currently written in the database. Can you somehow help me if I use the actual date datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for the *structured* part of *structured query language*.  That is, you will write some subqueries and treat them as tables.

You already know how to find the number of visits per day.  Let's add the month for each day to that query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8455e/13/0).

```
                   SELECT date DIV 100 as month, date, 
                          SUM(visits) as visits
                     FROM visits_tbl
                    GROUP BY date
```

Next you need to find the largest number of daily visits in each month. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8455e/12/0)

```
       SELECT month, MAX(visits) max_daily_visits
         FROM (
                   SELECT date DIV 100 as month, date, 
                          SUM(visits) as visits
                     FROM visits_tbl
                    GROUP BY date
              ) dayvisits
        GROUP BY month
```

Then, the trick is retrieving the date on which that maximum occurred in each month.  That requires a join.  Without [common table expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/) (which MySQL lacks) you need to repeat the first subquery. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8455e/11/0)

```
SELECT detail.*
  FROM (
           SELECT month, MAX(visits) max_daily_visits
             FROM (
                       SELECT date DIV 100 as month, date, 
                              SUM(visits) as visits
                         FROM visits_tbl
                        GROUP BY date
                  ) dayvisits
            GROUP BY month
        ) maxvisits
   JOIN (
                       SELECT date DIV 100 as month, date, 
                              SUM(visits) as visits
                         FROM visits_tbl
                        GROUP BY date
        ) detail ON detail.visits = maxvisits.max_daily_visits
                AND detail.month = maxvisits.month
```

The outline of this rather complex query helps explain it. Instead of that subquery, we'll use an imaginary table called `dayvisits`.

```
SELECT detail.*
  FROM (
           SELECT month, MAX(visits) max_daily_visits
             FROM dayvisits 
            GROUP BY date DIV 100
        ) maxvisits
   JOIN dayvisits detail ON detail.visits = maxvisits.max_daily_visits
                        AND detail.month = maxvisits.month
```

You're seeking an extreme value for each `month` in the subquery. (This is a fairly standard sort of SQL operation.) To do that you find that value with a `MAX() ... GROUP BY` query. Then you join that to the subquery itself to find the other values corresponding to the extreme value.

If you did have common table expressions, the query would look like this. YOu might consider adopting the MySQL fork called MariaDB, which has CTEs.

```
WITH dayvisits AS (
       SELECT date DIV 100 as month, date, 
          SUM(visits) as visits
     FROM visits_tbl
    GROUP BY date
) 
SELECT dayvisits.*
  FROM (
           SELECT month, MAX(visits) max_daily_visits
             FROM dayvisits
            GROUP BY month
        ) maxvisits
   JOIN dayvisits ON dayvisits.visits = maxvisits.max_daily_visits
                AND dayvisits.month = maxvisits.month
```

Comment: Usually I use impala, which supports CTEs and I can easily achieve my results. I will give it a try and let you know wether it worked!

Answer (score 0):

[Query Check on MSSQL] its quick and efficient.

---

```
select visit_sum_day_wise.date 
, visit_sum_day_wise.Max_Visits
, visit_sum_day_wise.traffic_type
, LAST_VALUE(visit_sum_day_wise.visits) OVER(PARTITION BY 
visit_sum_day_wise.date  ORDER BY visit_sum_day_wise.date  ROWS BETWEEN 
UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS max_visit_per_day
from (
     select visits_tbl.date , visits_tbl.visits , visits_tbl.traffic_type
     ,max(visits_tbl.visits ) OVER (  PARTITION BY visits_tbl.date   ORDER 
     BY  visits_tbl.date  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND  0  
     PRECEDING) Max_visits
     from visits_tbl  
     ) as visit_sum_day_wise
where visit_sum_day_wise.visits    = (select max(visits_B.visits )  from 
visits_tbl visits_B where visits_B.Date =  visit_sum_day_wise.date )
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM5KI.png)